# Authentication Issue in Mobile and Desktop Versions

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, .net-4.5

I have an application, done in .net 4.5, but with different functionality in mobile and desktop versions.

In desktop version, application has a menu and needs to be restricted to Intranet users (using Windows Authentication). In mobile version, only one page is used and there is no menu (since only one page is used!).

My problem is that the mobile version does not need to use authentication and I am wondering if this is possible.

If a context is required: mobile version is used in a hand-held scanner, a barcode is scanned and decoded and decoded data is displayed. Field people using the scanner need not enter user id and password each time. However, in desktop version users need to be authenticated. Is this possible?

Comment: which are you using: mvc or webforms?

Comment: I am using webforms